# Cannot upload file to qcow2 image file using guestfish on rhel 7.3

Tags: kvm-virtualization, rhel7, qcow2

I am trying to write a temp file into a *qcow2* image file using `guestfish` as follows:

```
[root@localhost home]# guestfish --rw -i -a vm.qcow2 upload temp /home/
```

and faced the following problem:

```
libguestfs: error: lvs: lvm lvs --help:   Invalid units specification
```

My *libguestfs* version is :

```
guestfish 1.36.3rhel=7,release=6.el7_4.2,libvirt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list filesystems in guest first

```
[kvm-host]# guestfish -a base.qcow2 -i list-filesystems
/dev/sda1: xfs
```

Probably because your guest uses the lvm partition